# Type provider for MySql

Tags: mysql, f#, type-providers, f#-3.0, f#-data

I've been searching for an example on how to connect to a MySql database and use F# type providers but I could not find anything online.

Can anyone give me a clue? What - if any - extra packages do I need? Do I use `SqlDataConnection` or `SqlEntityConnection`.

Excuse my ignorance but I'm totally lost. Any and all help is appreciated. I love the idea of type providers and have a fair amount of experience with functional programing but it's the setup around this that gets me.

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh361033.aspx)??

Comment: Yes I have (that's the first thing that comes up on Google) but it's talking about SQL Server not MySql and it doesn't seem to work. Do I need some extra reference packages to make it work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think there is out-of-the box type provider that would work with MySQL at the moment. However, Ross McKinlay has been working on a better type provider for SQL databases (more generally). It currently works with MS SQL server and SQL Lite.

It should be possible to write an extension to support MySQL with fairly small amount of work (but sadly, it has not been done yet). See [his blog for details](http://www.pinksquirrellabs.com/author/pezi.aspx). I'm sure that contributions are welcome!

Comment: Ohh SQLite support would be nice, especially for testing purposes.  From C# side, even Entity Framework 6 support for SQLite is disappointing so far, only NHibernate seems to do just fine on that front...

Comment: Thanks Thomas for taking the time to reply! That is sad though. I mean type providers came out 2 years ago already and it such a great thing. I can't believe how few DBs are supported to this date. I guess I'll just have to wait, or learn some more F# and help out.

Comment: I agree that missing support for other databases is unfortunate! The problem is that the standard provider is just a wrapper for LINQ to Entities/SQL and so it isn't extensible. The new one should make this easier.

Answer (score 4):

I haven't tested this, but if [Entity Framework works with MySql](http://brice-lambson.blogspot.com/2012/10/entity-framework-on-mysql.html) (it does) and if F# has an [Entity Framework Type Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh362322.aspx) (it does) then I would expect the Entity Framework Type Provider to work with MySql.

Have you tried that approach?

Comment: I'm going to try that, but if you be so kind as to give me some pointers as to how to do that, it would be awesome. I'm a complete noob to .Net. I mean COMPLETE. I know a fair amount of Haskell so I think (read: hope) F# won't be that much of a learning curve... Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

If you are still interested, I recently added support for MySQL to my [SQL type provider](https://github.com/fsprojects/SQLProvider), help with testing would be good!

Comment: Is this project still alive ? It seems to be only a beta stage.

Comment: it is very much alive, it is pretty hard to contribute to though so it moves fairly slowly with only myself at the controls.  Mostly I need help with testing on various platforms / database vendor combinations and so forth. Without this I will never really be confident to move it from a beta stage.  Lots of people are using it though I believe.

Answer (score 1):

> A general SQL database type provider, supporting LINQ queries, schema
>   exploration, individuals and much more besides.
>
> The provider currently supports MS SQL Server, SQLite, PostgreSQL,
>   Oracle, MySQL and MS Access. All database vendors except SQL Server
>   and MS Access will require 3rd party ADO.NET connector objects to
>   function. These are dynamically loaded at runtime so that the SQL
>   provider project is not dependent on them. You must supply the
>   location of the assemblies with the "ResolutionPath" static parameter.

https://fsprojects.github.io/SQLProvider/

Answer (score 0):

I think I actually got it to work!! Here's what I did:

- Installed the MySql Connector
- Added to and referenced MySql.Data & MySql.Data.Entity in my project
- Added and EntityFramework 5.0 to my project
- Added both MySql.Data & MySql.Data.Entity to the GAC.

Then I was able to use SqlEntityConnection and get the types!

There's gotta be an easier way to do this though. I particular, adding stuff to the GAC should not be a part of all this process. I mean, am I asking to much for this to work pretty much "out of the box"?!

Unfortunately, I'm extremely unfamiliar with .Net yet, so I couldn't get the whole thing working with the App.config file. Based on my searches here, it looks like I'm not the only one having troubles with this. If anyone has any feedback/suggestions please help!